# Request api gist of github Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api

I am having difficulty making the request for the github api gist in swift. Here are the codes:
I was wondering how I can get this data from the gist return to display on the screen.

Response:(https://api.github.com/gists/95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc)

```
   {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc/forks",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc/commits",
    "id": "95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc",
    "node_id": "MDQ6R2lzdDk1ZmNmNzFlYjcyZjJlYTFlMzgzNmQxOTJjNzg4ZWJj",
    "git_pull_url": "https://gist.github.com/95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc.git",
    "git_push_url": "https://gist.github.com/95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc.git",
    "html_url": "https://gist.github.com/95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc",
    "files": {
        "gist.swift": {
            "filename": "gist.swift",
            "type": "text/plain",
            "language": "Swift",
            "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/arjdev69/95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc/raw/60db0c3f01cffdd56bcfd3474d19d533c02dc0f2/gist.swift",
            "size": 2534,
            "truncated": false,
            "content": "//\n//  SceneDelegate.swift\n//"
        }
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2021-04-21T00:48:19Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T01:31:18Z",
    "description": "Ios Gist App",
    "comments": 1,
    "user": null,
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/95fcf71eb72f2ea1e3836d192c788ebc/comments"....continue
}
```

Model:

```
import UIKit

struct GistModel: Decodable {
  let id:String;

  var files:String;
  let created_at:String;
  let updated_at:String;
  let comments:Int;

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case files
    case created_at
    case updated_at
    case comments
    case id
  }


}

struct GistList: Decodable {
  let all: [GistModel]

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     case all
  }
}
```

API:

```
 func getGistById(_ id:String, completion:@escaping(_ data:GistModel) -> Void){
    guard let url = URL(string: urlService + "\(id)") else {return}
    
    let request = AF.request(url)

    request.responseDecodable(of: GistModel.self) { (response) in
        print(response)
      guard let gist = response.value else { return }
        completion(gist)
   }

}
```

I'm having problems decoding the response, especially the "Files" attribute.

Here is the error:

```
failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "files", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)))))
```

Comment: This question is very vague, "having difficulty" could be anything. Explain in more detail what your issue is.

Comment: What's the issue? Did you do the request correctly? Did you parsed with success? Now, you want what? Access `raw_url`? Do a request on that URL? Do you have errors?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to make the decodable, I'm getting the following error: failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "files", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)))))

Comment: `var files:String;`, does it seem like a `String` to you? No, you need another `struct` intermediary struct to handle `filename`, `type`, `raw_url`, etc. it's more `let files [String: ThatOtherStructWhichRepresentAFile]`

Comment: Thanks, I will implement this.